# Passing a hash in params and cannot decode it in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hashmap, parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

In a radio button form helper I have this code:

```
f.radio_button :list, {list_id: list.id, activate: false}
```

This returns the following params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wyFM3KzxGwn4UF/uSjaKM8Ld9UFv6MnQKg6mMNKO1ZM=", "user"=>{"list"=>"{:list_id=>28, :activate=>true}"}, "id"=>"341"}
```

But trying to do this in the controller:

```
list_id = params.require(:user).permit(:list)[:list_id]
```

Returns the following error:

"no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

It seems like the hash is read a String and the symbol cannot be read. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

you should write:

```
f.radio_button :list, list.id
```

then you will have: `params[:user][:list] => "28"`

in your case you have: `params[:user][:list] => "{:list_id=>28, :activate=>true}"` where your value is not `Hash` but `String`, this happens because you pass value to your `radio_button` as `{list_id: list.id, activate: false}` which was converted to string (because radio button can't send hash, just string)

if you need some additional data you could pass it with `input type="hidden"`, of course you can parse your `"{list_id: list.id, activate: false}"` string, but it looks unusual

Comment: Passing additional data with hidden is a good idea, bc I need to pass more data than normal. That's why this problem occured in the first place.

Comment: you could ask new question about how organize your data in form and pass it to controller, because this one doesn't contain data about form and is just about your `radiou_button` (which shouldn't be use in way which you have)